# Is there a way to run one query instead of those two in PosgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

The first query is:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom_kiosk, 250)::geometry(Polygon, 32618)) as geom 
FROM tbl_kiosk 
WHERE cte = 'ctejeremie' 
      and status = 'functional' and type = 'public';
```

The second query is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_buffer (geom_buffer, distance, cte, date_added) 
VALUES(geom, 250,'ctejeremie', now());
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to nest the first query inside the second where you have used `geom`?

Comment: Yes, but i have found a solution. I compiled the second and the first: INSERT INTO tbl_buffer (geom_buffer, distance, cte, date_added)
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom_kiosk, 250)::geometry(Polygon, 32618)), '250', 'ctejeremie', NOW()::date FROM tbl_kiosk 
WHERE cte = 'ctejeremie' and status = 'functional' and type = 'private';

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_buffer (geom_buffer, distance, cte, date_added)
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom_kiosk, 250)::geometry(Polygon, 32618)), '250', 'ctejeremie', NOW()::date 
FROM tbl_kiosk 
WHERE cte = 'ctejeremie' and status = 'functional' and type = 'private';
```